# Combining general dependencies with specific dependencies

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to put in a makefile, both a generic dependency such as:

```
%.o: %.c
```

and specific dependencies such as:

```
Tree.o: Leaf.h
Rectangle.o: Point.h
```

?

The final outcome should be that Tree.o depends both on Tree.c and Leaf.h, and Rectangle.o depends both on Rectangle.c and Point.h.

Where exactly should I put the compilation command in this case - below the general dependency or the specific dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can. And you usually add your recipe to the dependency involving the source file; this gives you access to the most useful make automatic variables (`$<`: first prerequisite - the source file and `$@`: the target object file):

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

foo.o: foo.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies are augmented in this way only if they are not part of a recipe, so you must not add any commands at all in this case.  The makefile fragments in your question are essentially the right way to do this.  See [Multiple Rules for One Target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html) in the GNU make manual.